# Using map with queue in c++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, queue

When try to run below piece of code,It compiles without any errors.

```
int main()
{
    queue<map<int,int> >run_time;
}
```

But,now when I try to push something into the queue using the below code.

```
int main()
{
    queue<map<int,int> >run_time;

    run_time.push(make_pair(1,2));
    run_time.push(make_pair(3,4));
}
```

I get error as :

`no matching function for call to 'std::queue<std::map<int,int,std::less<int>,std::allocator<std::pair<const int,int>`

Comment: Why do you think you need a `queue<map<int, int> >` in the first place? What are you trying to accomplish? While there may be real uses for this combination, it seems to me as if you may really want something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `make_pair` doesn't create a `map`. You'll need to create the map beforehand, insert into it with `make_pair`, and insert the map itself into the `queue`.

```
map<int,int> x;
x.insert(make_pair(1,2));
run_time.push(x);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a queue of maps, not a queue of pairs. You need to push maps into it.

Answer (score 0):

From the code given in the question it looks like you want to create a Queue for which each element of Queue is a group of two other elements. This can be easily done using class template "pair" or "tuple".

For **pair**[1] you write `template <class T1, class T2> struct pair;` while for **tuple**[2] `template <class... Types> class tuple;`

Tuple is generalization of pair where more than two members can form group. What I feel is wrong in your code is that you are initializing a map but not using it as a Map, you want to push individual elements of Map in Queue which demolish the purpose of creating a Map. Pair and Tuple create individual objects which can be treated separately from other similar objects, they act similar to as using **struct** to form group of different data types.

[1]. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/

[2]. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/